# Sanitize inputs before filling with user data?

Tags: javascript, html

When binding previous user input data to an HTML input, is it necessary to sanitize the input before filling the input field with it?

I know the importance of sanitizing user inputs **before rendering** them on the page. But, say a user's input is saved to a database, retrieved, then assigned to a variable. The variable is then data-bound to an input. Upon sanitizing the input (both at the time of binding and on every `oninput` or `onchange` event), it gives a poor user experience when typing a prohibited character.

For example: every time a "&" character is typed by the user it is immediately changed to "`&amp;`" in the input field. It'd be annoying if StackOverflow did this though.

Answer (score 0):

You're right, that wouldn't be a good solution, but sanitizing before rendering is still a good idea.

Just sanitize the value before storing it in the bound variable, it's fine if the user types scripts in the input field after that. If you *use* the value of the input sanitize it again before that.

Comment: If it's sanitized before storing in the bound variable, the input field will still show "&amp;" in the input string.

Comment: Yes, but the OP just indicated they didn't want a user's input to be converted *as they type*. You have a point, though: maybe they should consider re-encoding HTML entity codes to put in the input field.

Answer (score 0):

html-encode the value taken from the input control. html-decode previously html-encoded value before placing it into the input control.

It helps to know the encode state of the value before handling it.